# Show bootstrap modal dialog background, before dialog loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am loading content into a bootstrap modal dialog via jquery.  (I am using bootbox addon for dynamic modal dialog creation)

```
$.ajax({
        url: "create.cshtml",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            bootbox.dialog(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            HandleError(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Now this all works fine.

But what I want to do is show the fade in background while I wait for the aync call to complete so the user can see it's loading.  I can't see anything in the docs about showing the modal background but I presume there must be a way to trigger it before I perform the async call.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$("YOUR_BACKGROUND").fadeIn("slow", function(){

//MAKE YOUR AJAX CALL HERE

});
```

Comment: I really wanted to avoid handling the showing / hiding of the background.  That's why I wanted to trigger the bootstraps background early.

Comment: I have ended up doing something like this I have modified bootbox to give me the loading behavior but I actually insert the bootstrap modal-background div my self manually